# Dynamic arrangement of SQL pivoted columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

My Data -

```
CREATE TABLE Tbl1 (State varchar(max), Value int)
INSERT INTO Tbl1 VALUES 
('A',10),
('B',20),
('C1',30),
('C3',40),
('D',50),
('C2',70),
('E',60);
```

Scenario/Problem -  I want any state starting with C stacked in the end. If a new state for example C2 is added then the query should be able to detect and insert C2 as a column in between C1 and C3. If state E is added then it should be added as a column after D.

Required Output -

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| A  | B  | D  | E  | C1 | C2 | C3 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 10 | 20 | 50 | 60 | 30 | 70 | 40 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: C2 is missing from the sample table

Comment: C2 and E added. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
From Tbl1 A
Pivot (sum(Value) 
  For [State] in (' + Stuff((Select ',' + QuoteName([State]) 
                               From ( Select top 10000 [State] 
                                       From  Tbl1 
                                       Group By [State] 
                                       Order By Len([State]),[State]
                                     ) A For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') 
                  ) p
'

--Print @SQL
Exec(@SQL);
```

**Returns**

```
A   B   D   E   C1  C2  C3
10  20  50  60  30  70  40
```

Comment: I should note that if the numbers exceed 9, this will fail

Comment: You can use `TOP 100 PERCENT` to ensure you do not miss anything

Comment: @RyanH I've seen issues with 100 PERCENT in these situations, so I pick a ridiculous number.